# How do I create an FL algorithm that uses the weights of a few clients?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-federated

Based on this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/tree/3c0852c5fef375198f5931ce31fd97f2df9c4d05/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg) I am trying to write a new way of FL algorithm. I train all clients and send the model parameters of all clients to the server, and the server will weight average only the model parameters of 30% of all clients during the aggregation process. As a criterion for selecting model parameters of 30% of clients, I want to do a weighted average by using `weights_delta` of 30% of clients with less `loss_sum` of clients.

The code below is a modified code for this [link](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3c0852c5fef375198f5931ce31fd97f2df9c4d05/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tf.py#L191).

```
@tf.function
def client_update(model, dataset, server_message, client_optimizer):

model_weights = model.weights
initial_weights = server_message.model_weights
tff.utils.assign(model_weights, initial_weights)

num_examples = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.int32)
loss_sum = tf.constant(0, dtype=tf.float32)

for batch in iter(dataset):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        outputs = model.forward_pass(batch)
    grads = tape.gradient(outputs.loss, model_weights.trainable)
    grads_and_vars = zip(grads, model_weights.trainable)
    client_optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars)
    batch_size = tf.shape(batch['x'])[0]
    num_examples += batch_size
    loss_sum += outputs.loss * tf.cast(batch_size, tf.float32)        

weights_delta = tf.nest.map_structure(lambda a, b: a - b,
                                      model_weights.trainable,
                                      initial_weights.trainable)
client_weight = tf.cast(num_examples, tf.float32)

client_loss = loss_sum #add

return ClientOutput(weights_delta, client_weight, loss_sum / client_weight,client_loss)
```

There are the following attributes in `client_output`

```
weights_delta = attr.ib()
client_weight = attr.ib()
model_output = attr.ib()
client_loss = attr.ib()
```

After that, I made the `client_output` in the form of a sequence through
`collected_output = tff.federated_collect(client_output)` and `round_model_delta = tff.federated_map(selecting_fn,(collected_output,weight_denom))`in [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/b13046fa47b2eab4f38c37fc41d7fba64f192bb1/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L111) .

```
   @tff.federated_computation(federated_server_state_type,
                           federated_dataset_type)

    def run_one_round(server_state, federated_dataset):
    
    server_message = tff.federated_map(server_message_fn, server_state)
    server_message_at_client = tff.federated_broadcast(server_message)

    client_outputs = tff.federated_map(
        client_update_fn, (federated_dataset, server_message_at_client))

    weight_denom = client_outputs.client_weight

    collected_output = tff.federated_collect(client_outputs)  # add        
    
    round_model_delta = tff.federated_map(selecting_fn,(collected_output,weight_denom)) #add       

    server_state = tff.federated_map(server_update_fn,(server_state, round_model_delta))

    round_loss_metric = tff.federated_mean(client_outputs.model_output, weight=weight_denom)

    return server_state, round_loss_metric
```

Also, the following code is added [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/federated/blob/3c0852c5fef375198f5931ce31fd97f2df9c4d05/tensorflow_federated/python/examples/simple_fedavg/simple_fedavg_tff.py#L107) to implement the `selecting_fn` function.

```
@tff.tf_computation()  # append
def selecting_fn(collected_output,weight_denom):
    #TODO
    return round_model_delta
```

I am not sure if it is correct to write the code in the above way.
I tried in various ways, but mainly `TypeError: The value to be mapped must be a FederatedType or implicitly convertible to a FederatedType (got a <<model_weights=<trainable=<float32[5,5,1,32],float32[32] ,float32[5,5,32,64],float32[64],float32[3136,512],float32[512],float32[512,10],float32[10]>,non_trainable=<>>,optimizer_state= <int64>,round_num=int32>@SERVER,{<float32[5,5,1,32],float32[32],float32[5,5,32,64],float32[64],float32[3136,512 ],float32[512],float32[512,10],float32[10]>}@CLIENTS>)` I get this error.

I wonder how the sequence type `collected_output` accesses each client's `client_loss(= loss_sum)` and sorts them, and also wonders what method to use when calculating the weighted average with `weight_denom` applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One issue I see is that in the call `tff.federated_map(selecting_fn,(collected_output,weight_denom)`, the `collected_output` will be placed at `tff.SERVER` and the `weight_denom` will be placed at `tff.CLIENTS`, so that will not work. I think you want to get everything to `tff.SERVER` first.

I am not sure what you behavior you need, but here is a sample code which you can start from and develop. It starts from a client value (say its ID), samples a random value, collects (ID, value) pairs to the server, and then selects the pairs with largest value -- seems similar to what you describe.

```py
@tff.tf_computation()
def client_sample_fn():
  return tf.random.uniform((1,))

# Type annotation optional for tff.tf_computation. Added here for clarity.
idx_sample_type = tff.to_type(((tf.int32, (1,)), (tf.float32, (1,))))
@tff.tf_computation(tff.SequenceType(idx_sample_type))
def select_fn(idx_sample_dataset):  # Inside, this is a tf.data.Dataset.
  # Concatenate all pairs in the dataset.
  concat_fn = lambda a, b: tf.concat([a, b], axis=0)
  reduce_fn = lambda x, y: (concat_fn(x[0], y[0]), concat_fn(x[1], y[1]))
  reduce_zero = (tf.constant((), dtype=tf.int32, shape=(0,)),
                 tf.constant((), dtype=tf.float32, shape=(0,)))
  idx_tensor, sample_tensor = idx_sample_dataset.reduce(reduce_zero, reduce_fn)
  # Find 3 largest samples.
  top_3_val, top_3_idx = tf.math.top_k(sample_tensor, k=3)
  return tf.gather(idx_tensor, top_3_idx), top_3_val

@tff.federated_computation(tff.type_at_clients((tf.int32, (1,))))
def fed_fn(client_idx):
  client_sample = tff.federated_eval(client_sample_fn, tff.CLIENTS)
  # First zip, to have a dataset of pairs, rather than a pair of datasets.
  client_idx_sample_pair = tff.federated_zip((client_idx, client_sample))
  collected_idx_sample_pair = tff.federated_collect(client_idx_sample_pair)
  return tff.federated_map(select_fn, collected_idx_sample_pair)

client_idx = [(10,), (11,), (12,), (13,), (14,)]
fed_fn(client_idx)
```

With a sample output:

`(array([11, 10, 14], dtype=int32), array([0.8220736 , 0.81413555, 0.6984291 ], dtype=float32))`

Comment: Thanks to the sample code you made, it is very helpful in development.
Several questions arose during development based on your code.
I want to average by including `weights_delta` of the 3 selected samples. Therefore, I want to zip the `client_outputs.weights_delta` as well. The format of `weights_delta` is `<float32[5,5,1,32],float32[32],float32[5,5,32,64],float32[64,]float32[3136,512], float32[512 ,10],float32[10]>`. For example, how do I get the format `client_idx[1st client],client_outputs.client_loss[798.1616], client_output.weights_delta[...] `?