# TFF: What is difference between two type?

Tags: tensorflow-federated

[image]

`collected_output=tff.federated_collect(client_outputs)`.
Please refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66331850/how-do-i-create-an-fl-algorithm-that-uses-the-weights-of-a-few-clients) for detailed code.

My question is the difference between the parts marked in red on the photo. In terms of the FL algorithm, I think `client_outputs` is a individual client' output and `collected_output` is `SequenceType` because each `client_outputs` is combined. Is this correct? If my guess is correct, is `member` a set of individual client members with `client_outputs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The terminology maybe a bit tricky. `client_outputs` isn't quite an "individual client's output", it still represents *all* client outputs, but they aren't individually addressable. Importantly TFF distinguishes that the data lives ("is placed") at the clients, it has not been communicated. `collected_outputs` is in some sense a stream of all individual client outputs, though the *placement* has changed (the values were communicated) to the server via `tff.federated_collect`.

In a bit more detail:
In the type specification above `.member` is an attribute on the [`tff.FederatedType`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/FederatedType). The TFF Guide [Federated Core > Type System](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/federated_core#type_system) is a good resource for more details about the different TFF types.

> `{int32}@CLIENTS` represents a federated value that consists of a set of potentially distinct integers, one per client device. Note that we are talking about a single federated value as encompassing multiple items of data that appear in multiple locations across the network. One way to think about it is as a kind of tensor with a "network" dimension, although this analogy is not perfect because TFF does not permit random access to member constituents of a federated value.

In the screenshot, `client_outputs` is also "placed" `@CLIENTS` (from the `.placement` attribute) and follows similar semantics: it has multiple values (one per client) but individual values are not addressable (i.e. the value does not behave like a Python `list`).

In contrast, the `collected_output` is placed `@SERVER`. Then this bullet:

> `<weights=float32[10,5],bias=float32[5]>@SERVER` represents a named tuple of weight and bias tensors at the server. Since we've dropped the curly braces, this indicates the all_equal bit is set, i.e., there's only a single tuple (regardless of how many server replicas there might be in a cluster hosting this value).

Notice the "*single* tuple" phrase, after `tff.federated_collect` there is a single sequence of values placed at the server. This sequence can be iterated over like a [stream](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_(computing)).